# Mongo - Treat null or undefined fieled as a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following situation:

Consider a collection with the following documents:

```
 [
   {
      '_id': ObjectId('somehting'),
      'date': null
   },
   {
      '_id': ObjectId('somehting'),
   },
   {
      '_id': ObjectId('somehting'),
      'date': '2015-01-01 12:12:12'
   },
   many others
 ]
```

Now I have the following query that finds documents with date between to values db.getCollection('validation_archive').find({'date': {$lte: '[date_here]', {$gte: '[date_here]'}}});

All works fine, except for the fields with null or nonexistent.

Is there anyway I can tell mongo to treat null as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?

Edit: I need to do this, so if the date sent in $gt is 0000-00-00 00:00:00, the query returns the document in result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a general query then no. You can always exlude them from results as in :

```js
db.getCollection('validation_archive').find({
    "date": { "$lte": date_to, "$gte" date_from, "$ne": null }
})
```

Or you can be "inclusive" with the "zero" or "epoch" date you suggest using `.aggregate()`:

```js
db.getCollection('validation_archive').aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$and": [
                    { "$gte": [ date_from, { "$ifNull": [ "$date", new Date(0) ] } ] },
                    { "$lte": [ date_to, { "$ifNull": [ "$date", new Date(0) ] } ] }
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

But in the context of what you are asking, then we would have to ask "What is the point".

Or even if you must:

```js
db.getCollection('validation_archive').aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "date": { "$ifNull": [ "$date", new Date(0) ] }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "date": { "$lte": date_to, "$gte" date_from } }, 
            { "date": { "$eq": Date(0) } }
        ]
    }}
])
```

And that is completely inclusive in results.

But then again why not just do:

```js
db.getCollection('validation_archive').find({
   "$or": [
        { "date": { "$lte": date_to, "$gte" date_from },
        { "date": null },
        { "date": { "$exists": false } }
   ]
})
```

Which is a lot more efficient.

So it is possible to "project" as date where not present, but it mostly makes sense to simply use the basic query operations instead.

Comment: I don't want to exclude them from results, I want to include them in results if the $gt/$gte parameter is '00-00-00' . They come excluded by default. Edited question to reflect this.

Comment: @zozo You need to think about that as "00-00-00" is not within the range of "2015-01-01" and "2015-12-01" for example. Which is why I state *"What is the point"*. You can always `$project` and add an `$or` condition by `.aggregate()` if you need to.

Comment: @zozo Even added an example for you.

Comment: db.getCollection('validation_archive').find({
   "$or": [
        { "date": { "$lte": date_to, "$gte" date_from },
        { "date": null },
        { "date": { "$exists": false } }
   ]
}) This is almost what I need, but I need to add the {'date': null} and {'date': {$exists: false}} part only if the date_from is '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. I can do this by adding another $and and one more $or, but then the query gets pretty 'complex'. That's why I asked if you can treat null as a specified value (as you can in sql). I guess you can't :). So... upvoted+accepted.

Comment: @zozo Your wrong, but accepting is the correct thing to do until you realize that I am right.

Comment: Faced this today, it's awful. But `$lte : null` instead of `eq : null` works like a charm: underined are "smaller" than nulls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to put value of date as 0 at the time of insert itself. It'll help you execute the query.
2. If the collection is already existing you can update the date field by using update queries.
3. Use mongo's projection technique to insert a new field, say, newDate with value either 0 or actual date. Use filter queries on newDate field after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude results having `date` equals to `null` or nonexistent, then

```
db.getCollection('validation_archive').find({
  date: {
    $ne: null,
    $lt: '[date_here]',
    $gt: '[date_here]'
  }
});
```